# Write column on csv

Tags: python

I have a csv file. I want to write its columns on another file after I modified them.
I tried to transpose the csv file and write each line, then transpose the result again.
However, this takes too much time.

I then tried somthing like:

```
my_reader = csv.reader(source, delimiter = delim)
my_writer = csv.writer(destination, delimiter = delim)

for column in zip(*my_reader):
        my_writer.writerows(column)
```

and

```
for column in zip(*my_reader):
    for k in column:
        my_writer.writerow[k]
```

In the first case, the result is a csv file with four columns (I don't know why, since the original test file has over a hundred columns).

In the second case, the result is written in a single column.

How can I write each column separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open(source) as fin, open(destination, 'w') as fout:
   reader = csv.reader(fin, delimiter=delim)
   writer = csv.writer(fout, delimiter=delim)
   for line in reader:
      line[0] = 42   # manipulate existing the column
      line.append('new column')  # Add a new column
      writer.writerow(line)
```

Comment: you can also use `open(destination, 'a')` in append mode so you can just read a line and write/append it in the output file

Comment: @Burhan and abhishekgarg For each column, I need to check a condition like: if columnId in list: do_this; else: do_that So I need to write column by column. Thanks!